Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI' when using a forked version of the repo
I am having some trouble figuring out why these imports are throwing Typescript errors specifically when using my forked version of the repo react-pivottable. To be clear, the data from these imports work perfectly fine in the code, it's just Typescript throwing erorrs. So, if I toss a //@ts-ignore in there, everything runs smoothly. And, when I am using the base repo, these errors do not show up, only when I've installed the package from my forked repo.
Full Error Message:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI'. '...projectname/node_modules/react-pivottable/PivotTableUI.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-pivottable` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';`ts(7016)

The imports in question:
import PivotTableUI, { PivotTableUIProps } from 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';
import createPlotlyRenderers from 'react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers';
import TableRenderers from 'react-pivottable/TableRenderers';

My relevant package json lines:
"dependencies": {
...
    "react-pivottable": "https://github.com/algould28/react-pivottable",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-pivottable": "https://github.com/algould28/react-pivottable"
  },

What's confusing me further is that I did not modify anything I'm importing in my forked version of the repo. And, these files exist in my node_modules and contain the relevant exports. For example PivotTableUI is exported from react-pivottable/PivotTableUI.js. For reference:
File Location: /node_modules/react-pivottable/PivotTableUI.js
PivotTableUI.js :
var PivotTableUI = function (_React$PureComponent2) {
  _inherits(PivotTableUI, _React$PureComponent2);

  function PivotTableUI(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, PivotTableUI);

    var _this5 = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (PivotTableUI.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(PivotTableUI)).call(this, props));

    _this5.state = {
      unusedOrder: [],
      zIndices: {},
      maxZIndex: 1000,
      openDropdown: false,
      attrValues: {},
      materializedInput: [],
      expanded: false
    };
    return _this5;
  }

  _createClass(PivotTableUI, [{
    key: 'componentDidMount',
    value: function componentDidMount() {
      this.materializeInput(this.props.data);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'componentDidUpdate',
    value: function componentDidUpdate() {
      this.materializeInput(this.props.data);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'materializeInput',
    value: function materializeInput(nextData) {
      if (this.state.data === nextData) {
        return;
      }
      var newState = {
        data: nextData,
        attrValues: {},
        materializedInput: []
      };
      var recordsProcessed = 0;
      _Utilities.PivotData.forEachRecord(newState.data, this.props.derivedAttributes, function (record) {
        newState.materializedInput.push(record);
        var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
        var _didIteratorError = false;
        var _iteratorError = undefined;

        try {
          for (var _iterator = Object.keys(record)[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
            var attr = _step.value;

            if (!(attr in newState.attrValues)) {
              newState.attrValues[attr] = {};
              if (recordsProcessed > 0) {
                newState.attrValues[attr].null = recordsProcessed;
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (err) {
          _didIteratorError = true;
          _iteratorError = err;
        } finally {
          try {
            if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
              _iterator.return();
            }
          } finally {
            if (_didIteratorError) {
              throw _iteratorError;
            }
          }
        }

        for (var _attr in newState.attrValues) {
          var value = _attr in record ? record[_attr] : 'null';
          if (!(value in newState.attrValues[_attr])) {
            newState.attrValues[_attr][value] = 0;
          }
          newState.attrValues[_attr][value]++;
        }
        recordsProcessed++;
      });
      this.setState(newState);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'sendPropUpdate',
    value: function sendPropUpdate(command) {
      this.props.onChange((0, _immutabilityHelper2.default)(this.props, command));
    }
  }, {
    key: 'propUpdater',
    value: function propUpdater(key) {
      var _this6 = this;

      return function (value) {
        return _this6.sendPropUpdate(_defineProperty({}, key, { $set: value }));
      };
    }
  }, {
    key: 'setValuesInFilter',
    value: function setValuesInFilter(attribute, values) {
      this.sendPropUpdate({
        valueFilter: _defineProperty({}, attribute, {
          $set: values.reduce(function (r, v) {
            r[v] = true;
            return r;
          }, {})
        })
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'addValuesToFilter',
    value: function addValuesToFilter(attribute, values) {
      if (attribute in this.props.valueFilter) {
        this.sendPropUpdate({
          valueFilter: _defineProperty({}, attribute, values.reduce(function (r, v) {
            r[v] = { $set: true };
            return r;
          }, {}))
        });
      } else {
        this.setValuesInFilter(attribute, values);
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'removeValuesFromFilter',
    value: function removeValuesFromFilter(attribute, values) {
      this.sendPropUpdate({
        valueFilter: _defineProperty({}, attribute, { $unset: values })
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'moveFilterBoxToTop',
    value: function moveFilterBoxToTop(attribute) {
      this.setState((0, _immutabilityHelper2.default)(this.state, {
        maxZIndex: { $set: this.state.maxZIndex + 1 },
        zIndices: _defineProperty({}, attribute, { $set: this.state.maxZIndex + 1 })
      }));
    }
  }, {
    key: 'isOpen',
    value: function isOpen(dropdown) {
      return this.state.openDropdown === dropdown;
    }
  }, {
    key: 'makeDnDCell',
    value: function makeDnDCell(items, onChange, classes, collapseable) {
      var _this7 = this;

      var collapseableAndExpanded = collapseable && this.state.expanded;

      return _react2.default.createElement(
        _reactSortablejs2.default,
        {
          options: {
            group: 'shared',
            ghostClass: 'pvtPlaceholder',
            filter: '.pvtFilterBox',
            preventOnFilter: false
          },
          tag: 'td',
          className: classes + (collapseable ? ' pvtCollapseable' : ''),
          onChange: onChange,
          style: {
            maxHeight: collapseableAndExpanded ? '1000px' : '47px'
          }
        },
        items.sort().map(function (x) {
          return _react2.default.createElement(DraggableAttribute, {
            name: x,
            key: x,
            attrValues: _this7.state.attrValues[x],
            valueFilter: _this7.props.valueFilter[x] || {},
            sorter: (0, _Utilities.getSort)(_this7.props.sorters, x),
            menuLimit: _this7.props.menuLimit,
            setValuesInFilter: _this7.setValuesInFilter.bind(_this7),
            addValuesToFilter: _this7.addValuesToFilter.bind(_this7),
            moveFilterBoxToTop: _this7.moveFilterBoxToTop.bind(_this7),
            removeValuesFromFilter: _this7.removeValuesFromFilter.bind(_this7),
            zIndex: _this7.state.zIndices[x] || _this7.state.maxZIndex
          });
        }),
        collapseable && !this.state.expanded && _react2.default.createElement(
          'div',
          {
            className: 'pvtExpand',
            onClick: function onClick() {
              return _this7.setState({ expanded: true });
            }
          },
          '+'
        ),
        collapseable && this.state.expanded && _react2.default.createElement(
          'div',
          {
            className: 'pvtExpand',
            onClick: function onClick() {
              return _this7.setState({ expanded: false });
            }
          },
          '\u2212'
        )
      );
    }
  }, {
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      var _this8 = this;

      var numValsAllowed = this.props.aggregators[this.props.aggregatorName]([])().numInputs || 0;

      var aggregatorCellOutlet = this.props.aggregators[this.props.aggregatorName]([])().outlet;

      var rendererName = this.props.rendererName in this.props.renderers ? this.props.rendererName : Object.keys(this.props.renderers)[0];

      var rendererCell = _react2.default.createElement(
        'td',
        { className: 'pvtRenderers' },
        _react2.default.createElement(Dropdown, {
          current: rendererName,
          values: Object.keys(this.props.renderers),
          open: this.isOpen('renderer'),
          zIndex: this.isOpen('renderer') ? this.state.maxZIndex + 1 : 1,
          toggle: function toggle() {
            return _this8.setState({
              openDropdown: _this8.isOpen('renderer') ? false : 'renderer'
            });
          },
          setValue: this.propUpdater('rendererName')
        })
      );

      var sortIcons = {
        key_a_to_z: {
          rowSymbol: '↕',
          colSymbol: '↔',
          next: 'value_a_to_z'
        },
        value_a_to_z: {
          rowSymbol: '↓',
          colSymbol: '→',
          next: 'value_z_to_a'
        },
        value_z_to_a: { rowSymbol: '↑', colSymbol: '←', next: 'key_a_to_z' }
      };

      var aggregatorCell = _react2.default.createElement(
        'td',
        { className: 'pvtVals' },
        _react2.default.createElement(Dropdown, {
          current: this.props.aggregatorName,
          values: Object.keys(this.props.aggregators),
          open: this.isOpen('aggregators'),
          zIndex: this.isOpen('aggregators') ? this.state.maxZIndex + 1 : 1,
          toggle: function toggle() {
            return _this8.setState({
              openDropdown: _this8.isOpen('aggregators') ? false : 'aggregators'
            });
          },
          setValue: this.propUpdater('aggregatorName')
        }),
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'a',
          {
            role: 'button',
            className: 'pvtRowOrder',
            onClick: function onClick() {
              return _this8.propUpdater('rowOrder')(sortIcons[_this8.props.rowOrder].next);
            }
          },
          sortIcons[this.props.rowOrder].rowSymbol
        ),
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'a',
          {
            role: 'button',
            className: 'pvtColOrder',
            onClick: function onClick() {
              return _this8.propUpdater('colOrder')(sortIcons[_this8.props.colOrder].next);
            }
          },
          sortIcons[this.props.colOrder].colSymbol
        ),
        numValsAllowed > 0 && _react2.default.createElement('br', null),
        new Array(numValsAllowed).fill().map(function (n, i) {
          return [_react2.default.createElement(Dropdown, {
            key: i,
            current: _this8.props.vals[i],
            values: Object.keys(_this8.state.attrValues).filter(function (e) {
              return !_this8.props.hiddenAttributes.includes(e) && !_this8.props.hiddenFromAggregators.includes(e);
            }),
            open: _this8.isOpen('val' + i),
            zIndex: _this8.isOpen('val' + i) ? _this8.state.maxZIndex + 1 : 1,
            toggle: function toggle() {
              return _this8.setState({
                openDropdown: _this8.isOpen('val' + i) ? false : 'val' + i
              });
            },
            setValue: function setValue(value) {
              return _this8.sendPropUpdate({
                vals: { $splice: [[i, 1, value]] }
              });
            }
          }), i + 1 !== numValsAllowed ? _react2.default.createElement('br', { key: 'br' + i }) : null];
        }),
        aggregatorCellOutlet && aggregatorCellOutlet(this.props.data)
      );

      var unusedAttrs = Object.keys(this.state.attrValues).filter(function (e) {
        return !_this8.props.rows.includes(e) && !_this8.props.cols.includes(e) && !_this8.props.hiddenAttributes.includes(e) && !_this8.props.hiddenFromDragDrop.includes(e);
      }).sort((0, _Utilities.sortAs)(this.state.unusedOrder));

      var unusedLength = unusedAttrs.reduce(function (r, e) {
        return r + e.length;
      }, 0);
      var horizUnused = unusedLength < this.props.unusedOrientationCutoff;

      var unusedAttrsCell = this.makeDnDCell(unusedAttrs, function (order) {
        return _this8.setState({ unusedOrder: order });
      }, 'pvtAxisContainer pvtUnused ' + (horizUnused ? 'pvtHorizList' : 'pvtVertList'), true);

      var colAttrs = this.props.cols.filter(function (e) {
        return !_this8.props.hiddenAttributes.includes(e) && !_this8.props.hiddenFromDragDrop.includes(e);
      });

      var colAttrsCell = this.makeDnDCell(colAttrs, this.propUpdater('cols'), 'pvtAxisContainer pvtHorizList pvtCols');

      var rowAttrs = this.props.rows.filter(function (e) {
        return !_this8.props.hiddenAttributes.includes(e) && !_this8.props.hiddenFromDragDrop.includes(e);
      });
      var rowAttrsCell = this.makeDnDCell(rowAttrs, this.propUpdater('rows'), 'pvtAxisContainer pvtVertList pvtRows');
      var outputCell = _react2.default.createElement(
        'td',
        { className: 'pvtOutput' },
        _react2.default.createElement(_PivotTable2.default, (0, _immutabilityHelper2.default)(this.props, {
          data: { $set: this.state.materializedInput }
        }))
      );

      if (horizUnused) {
        return _react2.default.createElement(
          'table',
          { className: 'pvtUi' },
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'tbody',
            { onClick: function onClick() {
                return _this8.setState({ openDropdown: false });
              } },
            _react2.default.createElement(
              'tr',
              null,
              rendererCell,
              unusedAttrsCell
            ),
            _react2.default.createElement(
              'tr',
              null,
              aggregatorCell,
              colAttrsCell
            ),
            _react2.default.createElement(
              'tr',
              null,
              rowAttrsCell,
              outputCell
            )
          )
        );
      }

      return _react2.default.createElement(
        'table',
        { className: 'pvtUi' },
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'tbody',
          { onClick: function onClick() {
              return _this8.setState({ openDropdown: false });
            } },
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'tr',
            null,
            rendererCell,
            aggregatorCell,
            colAttrsCell
          ),
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'tr',
            null,
            unusedAttrsCell,
            rowAttrsCell,
            outputCell
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }]);

  return PivotTableUI;
}(_react2.default.PureComponent);

PivotTableUI.propTypes = Object.assign({}, _PivotTable2.default.propTypes, {
  onChange: _propTypes2.default.func.isRequired,
  hiddenAttributes: _propTypes2.default.arrayOf(_propTypes2.default.string),
  hiddenFromAggregators: _propTypes2.default.arrayOf(_propTypes2.default.string),
  hiddenFromDragDrop: _propTypes2.default.arrayOf(_propTypes2.default.string),
  unusedOrientationCutoff: _propTypes2.default.number,
  menuLimit: _propTypes2.default.number
});

PivotTableUI.defaultProps = Object.assign({}, _PivotTable2.default.defaultProps, {
  hiddenAttributes: [],
  hiddenFromAggregators: [],
  hiddenFromDragDrop: [],
  unusedOrientationCutoff: 85,
  menuLimit: 500
});

exports.default = PivotTableUI;

This is not an app breaking error and can easily be ignored with a //@ts-ignore since everything works despite these errors. I would like to know why it's happening and how to fix it for the future though as I may be forking more repos for this project.
I have tried the following:

adding the build files to the forked repo
removing node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling everything
changing the import structures around
declaring module files (though I could have done this wrong)

